# What does NT_STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED mean when using smbclient to connect to a samba share?

Tags: 11.04, mount, samba, smb

Symptoms:

- You can mount a NetApp 'shared drive' using the `mount` program fine.
- But if you try to browse it using `smbclient`, you get this error when it fails to connect:

  `session setup failed: NT_STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED`

Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is a bug in Ubuntu 11.04

Workaround is to change your hostname to a short string, without any hypens (dashes) in it (really!)

[source](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/strange-fix-for-smb-problems-in-linux/)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer Will.

The bug seems to be still present (or reappeared ?) in 2018. I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and I got problems with `smbclient`.

Strangely, the error message from `smbclient` is:

> NT_STATUS_INVALID_NETWORK_RESPONSE

BUT, I recorded the packets with wireshark, and the actual status was:

> NT_STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED

As explained by Will, I changed my hostname to a shorter version, without hyphen, and it worked.